# how to make controls accessible from other threads in c++ builder xe2?

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I downloaded a trial of c++ builder xe2, and I'm trying to find out how to access and change control properties (Example: Change the text of a TLabel from a different thread). I know that you can  change it on the same thread by using:

```
Label1->Caption = " Text ";
```

But what I need to do is change it from another function. so far in the header file for the form I have:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Hello_VCLH
#define Hello_VCLH

#define IN
#define INOUT
#define OUT

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ComCtrls.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TLabel *Label1;
    TButton *Button1;
    TProgressBar *ProgressBar1;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm2(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

In .cpp file for the form, I tried putting TForm2::Label1->Caption = " test"; but that didn't work.
I tried putting static in front of the controls, but when I do that xe2 claims that the form code is wrong. Anyone know how to make it to where I can access the control from another function or thread besides the main one? Thanks!

EDIT**:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Hello_VCL.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "wimgapi.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}


DWORD
WINAPI
SampleCaptureCallback(
    IN      DWORD msgId,    //message ID
    IN      WPARAM param1,   //usually file name
    INOUT   LPARAM param2,   //usually error code
    IN      void  *unused
    )
{
    //First parameter: full file path for if WIM_MSG_PROCESS, message string for others
    TCHAR *message  = (TCHAR *) param1;
    TCHAR *filePath = (TCHAR *) param1;
    DWORD percent   = (DWORD)   param1;

    //Second parameter: message back to caller if WIM_MSG_PROCESS, error code for others
    DWORD errorCode = param2;
    DWORD *msg_back = (DWORD *) param2;
    DWORD seconds = (DWORD) param2;


    switch ( msgId )
    {
        case WIM_MSG_PROGRESS:

            // Prints out the current progress percentage.
            //

            //lbl->Caption="Test";

            Label1->Caption = (String)param1 + " % completed";
            //Label1->Caption = (DWORD)param1;
            //wprintf(L"__________________\n\n| Capture process|\t\t(c) 2012 Andrew Butler\n__________________\n\n%d %% captured. About %i seconds(s) remaining - %i minute(s)", (DWORD)param1, ((INT)seconds / 1000), ((INT)seconds / 60000));

            break;
        case WIM_MSG_PROCESS:

            //This message is sent for each file, capturing to see if callee intends to
            //capture the file or not.
            //
            //If you do not intend to capture this file, then assign FALSE in msg_back
            //and still return WIM_MSG_SUCCESS.
            //Default is TRUE.
            //

            //In this example, print out the file name being applied
            //
            //_tprintf(TEXT("FilePath: %s\n"), filePath);

            break;

        case WIM_MSG_ERROR:

            //This message is sent upon failure error case
            //
            //printf("ERROR: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_RETRY:

            //This message is sent when the file is being reapplied because of
            //network timeout. Retry is done up to five times.
            //
            //printf("RETRY: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_INFO:

            //This message is sent when informational message is available
            //
            //printf("INFO: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;

        case WIM_MSG_WARNING:

            //This message is sent when warning message is available
            //
            //printf("WARNING: %s [err = %d]\n", message, errorCode);
            break;
    }

    return WIM_MSG_SUCCESS;
}

void
SampleCaptureCleanup ( HANDLE hWim, HANDLE hImg, FARPROC callback )
{
    if (hImg) {
        WIMCloseHandle (hImg);
    }

    if (hWim) {
        WIMCloseHandle (hWim);
    }

    if (callback) {
        WIMUnregisterMessageCallback( NULL, callback );
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    //Label1->Caption = "Test";
}
```

EDIT 2 *** :

```
FARPROC callback = (FARPROC) SampleCaptureCallback;

if (WIMRegisterMessageCallback( NULL,
                                callback,
                                NULL ) == INVALID_CALLBACK_VALUE) {
    printf ("Cannot set callback\n");
    return 3;
}
```

I have edited it to include the cpp file. I want to change the label under case WIM_MSG_PROGRESS: in the SampleCallback function.

Comment: You could pass a pointer of the control you want to access to the other thread (e.g. at its creation), then you can access the control via that pointer.

_Note_: make sure to protect access to that control with some sort of mutex/semaphore to avoid race conditions on the access.  One way to do this would be to wrap access to the desirec control in a member function of the main form and pass the (pointer to the) main form to the thread, so it can call that function

Comment: I am new to c++, would you mind posting an example please? If I were to guess would I declare another TLabel in the header file or what exactly?

Comment: How do you start your other thread?

Comment: i updated my question with the cpp file. thanks!

Comment: Can you also post how you are registering your `SampleCaptureCallback` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of the `WIMRegisterMessageCallback` call specifies a custom user data you can use to pass information to your callback function (in its last parameter, currently named `unused`).

You could pass the pointer to your `TForm2` object to the callback by modifying the registering call to

```
WIMRegisterMessageCallback( NULL, callback, form)
```

where `form` is the above mentioned pointer.

Then you can use that user data in your callback as follows:

```
DWORD  WINAPI  SampleCaptureCallback(
  IN      DWORD msgId,
  IN      WPARAM param1,
  INOUT   LPARAM param2,
  IN      PVOID  udata)
{
  TForm2* form = reinterpret_cast<TForm2*>(udata);
  udata->SetLabel1Caption("my text");
  //...
}
```

where `SetLabel1Caption` is the following function of `TForm2`:

```
void SetLabel1Cation(String str)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(hLabel1Mutex, INFINITE);
  Label1->Caption = str;
  ReleaseMutex(hLabel1Mutex);
}
```

where `hLabel1` mutex is a member variable of `Tform2`

```
HANDLE hLabel1Mutex;
```

and is initilized in `TForm2`'s constructor as:

```
hLabel1Mutex = CreateMutex (NULL, FALSE, NULL);
if (hLabel1Mutex == NULL)
{
  // failed to create mutex, throw exception
}
```

*Note* this example is tailored to using only `Label1`.  If you want to update more than one controls at the same time, you can use use the same mutex otherwise you should protect each control with its own mutex.

*Note*: read more about mutexes in the Win32API [in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx) [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3x8b09y.aspx) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927.aspx) as a starter.

**Update**: Remy points out that the traditional protection mechanisms (mutex/semaphore) are not applicable here for full thread safety.  Instead the various threads need to work together and communicate with the main thread to delegate the access to the UI controls.

Comment: A mutex is NOT adequate protection in this case, because the main thread does not participate with it. VCL UI controls are simply not thread-safe and cannot be accessed from outside the context of the main thread. Period. A worker thread must delegate to the main thread to access the UI safely. Either use the static `TThread::Synchronize()` method, or use `AllocateHWnd()` to create a helper window that you can send custom messages to using `SendMessage()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thx for the correction, I was not aware of this limitation